# How To Spawn Selected Object with SpawnCount

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Get Object && Get its Count SpawnCount

spawn  All 20 Selected Object

[image: See Image]
Following Code Don't Matter Just Example.

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class ObjectToSpawn
{
    public GameObject Object;
    public int spawnCount;

}
public class LevelSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
 public ObjectToSpawn[] itemToSpawn; // Select Obstacles To spawn
    public int maxSpawnObject;  // Total Object or Sum of All Spawn Count.
}
```

Comment: What about using List<int> instead of int[]?

Comment: Time to try some googling.

Comment: @puzzlessouls instead of typing public int[] SpawnIndex, you can type in public List<int> SpawnIndex. It will do what you want it to do.

Comment: read about difference between lists and arrays in C#. it will be like @Swagrim 's comment.

Comment: Sorry My Question is How To Spawn Selected Object with SpawnCount

Comment: Should these be random?

Comment: @derHugo No Fixed SpawnCount total 20

Comment: yes but ... what if your amount is not happen to be 4+4+6+6 ? Like what shall happen if  MaxSpawnCount < sum of all amounts ?

Comment: @derHugo  i don't get what you mean. how to loop that, get 1st object[i] =spawn that with spawnCount[i] ,4+4+6+6 or if i change values 3+3+3+11

Comment: Yeah but what if you have 4+4+4+15+10 but MaxSpawnCount is 20 ? Do you want to "equally" spread the max spawns (with given weight) among the given options or simply not spawn any of the last item since the total amount is not enough and spawn them in order until MaxSpawnCount is exceeded? Or do you actually not want to have a MaxSpawnCount at all but simply spawn the full sum of given individual amounts?

Comment: @derHugo Yes simply not spawn any of the last item since the total amount is not enough and spawn them in order until MaxSpawnCount is exceeded

Comment: @AhmedAlayat in this case it doesn't actually matter since it is serialized and exposed in the Unity Inspector and configured there. In the Inspector you can still dynamically add and remove items and change their order also for arrays ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after clarifying things in the comments I'd say you simply want to do

```
public class LevelSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ObjectToSpawn[] itemToSpawn; 
    public int maxSpawnObject;

    // Wherever this is called e.g. in "Awake"
    public void Spawn()
    {
        // Keep track how many things you spawned in total
        var counter = 0;

        // iterate given items in order
        foreach(var item in itemToSpawn)
        {
            // Iterate spawnCount times for the current item
            for(var i = 0; i < item.spawnCount; i++)
            {
                // spawn the item
                Instantiate(item.Object);

                // increase the counter
                counter++;

                // return if max count is exceeded
                if(counter >= maxSpawnObject) return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```